# TextView not giving feedback when clicked, despite being "clickable"

Tags: android, button, textview, click

I have TextView that responds to clicks, but that doesn't give any feedback showing it has been clicked. How do I give the TextView the standard android behavior of "lighting up" when clicked?

Code:

```
TextView tv = ( TextView ) view.findViewById ( R.id.test );
    tv.setOnClickListener ( new OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            Toast.makeText ( getActivity (), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }

    } );
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="test" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `selector` with a default and a `pressed` state, and change the colour accordingly with the state. Put this selector as background for your `TextView`

Comment: Hmm, how do I make that background match the default used for other buttons on the current platform?

Comment: what does "on the current platform" mean?

Comment: For instance, I'm running "vanilla 4.3", so the default background color for selected buttons is blue. That seems to differ between platforms.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I'll dive in the the documentation. Selectors you say... thanks. :)

Comment: well those are defined by the theme you are using. So you should start with getTheme() from ContextThemeWrapper I think. But I never tried it. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#getTheme())